# Datatable Filter in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Datatable filter is not able apply for Datatable which is stored in session.

Can anyone give me a clue on this issue ?

Comment: can you please provide you code so we can suggest you some better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  private void CopyDataTable(DataTable table){
    // Create an object variable for the copy.
    DataTable copyDataTable;
    copyDataTable = table.Copy();

    // Insert code to work with the copy.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to copy the datatable instead of just assigning it. I'm assuming you are doing something like this:

```
dim NewDatatable as datatable = session("sessiontable")
```

I'm not 100%, but I think all this will do is assign a memory pointer. Try:

```
dim NewDatatable as datatable = ctype(session("sessiontable"), datatable).copy()
```

Not 100% on syntax, but should be pretty close

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow[] dr=table.select("filter");

Datatable dt= dr.CopyToDataTable();
```

I hope can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataView.RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx).

```
dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter="columnName='expressionValue'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the DataTable by

```
DatatTableObject.DefualtView.RowFilter = "filter string";
DatatTableObject = DatatTableObject.DefualtView.ToTable();
```